# Small business wireless network for 2 DSL connections

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

We've been trying to improve internet access reliability for 15 users. We currently have 2 independent DSL channels with ZTE modem/wireless access points.

We've identified that:

1. The wireless on this routers are horrible bad, we need new wireless access points.
2. We want to change the modems too if we can find a good one.

Ideally we want to have the 2 modems connect into 1 single wireless router that can handle both connections intelligently (if one goes down, the other continues etc), so the users can't tell. We're also open to changing both DSL modems.

Can anyone recommend a great wireless router that can do this for us (budget is $1,000 and $300 extra for 2 modems).

Comment: Not a good fit for this site as you're "[asking for a shopping or product recommendation](http://superuser.com/faq)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopping recommendations aren't a good fit for this site, but I can tell you what you want to look for.

*Loadbalancing* outbound connections is known as *multi-homing* or *multi-WAN*. You can build yourself a pretty robust router which supports this with off-the-shelf X86 hardware (i.e., an old computer) and the router OS pfSense for far less than $1000. It will require you to get your hands dirty, though.

pfSense is fully capable of detecting when a modem fails and automatically failover to the remaining connection, and then properly redistribute connections across both modems when the first one recovers and comes back up. It is also capable of serving as a wireless access point if you put a wireless card in the system (driver support isn't the best though).

---

You can easily grab two consumer-grade wireless access points for ~$160 (check if you can get by with just one first! You should get pretty solid range from a decent AP), and you should be able to build or buy a cheap computer for < $500 and add some gigabit network cards to run pfSense on.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, exactly what I needed to know. I bought a cisco multi wan balancer: http://www.amazon.com/Cisco-RV042-4-port-100-Router/dp/B0002I7288/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1368806649&sr=8-2&keywords=cisco+multi+wan+router and a wireless router and made it work as a Access Point.